# How to make Android 5.0 as a USB Mass Storage?

Tags: android, usb

Is there any way to make Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0) an USB Mass Storage? I know there was a feature like this a while ago, but not any more.
Or any way to make this feature programmatically?